# Installing GDAL Python binding in Ubuntu to use as standalone module

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, blender, gdal

I am trying to export a GeoTiff with Blender using the Blender Python API (based on Python 3), so I've decided to install GDAL on Ubuntu (14.04). What I would like is to get the module as a standalone folder that I could put in the modules directory of Blender (/home/user/.config/blender/2.73/scripts/modules).

The thing is I've run through several different problems trying to install GDAL. I've tried to install from source (for GDAL 2.0.0) here : [Official PyPi Gdal](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/)

- I ran `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev gdal-bin` (I list it here because it may be important)
- When I am in the extracted GDAL folder, using `python setup.py build & python setup.py install`, the library installs to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo`. However, when I run `python` from command line, running `from osgeo import osr` returns `ImportError: No module named _gdal`
- Following [GDAL via pip](http://www.iup.uni-bremen.de/~hilboll/blog/2013/2013-10_installing-gdal-in-a-virtualenv.html) , I used pip (`pip install GDAL`) to install the library, and the folder it went to was `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo` (using `pip show ...`). Again, running `python3` and trying to import results in the same error. Of course, when I copy-paste each folder in the blender module directory, I get the same error in the Blender Python console.
- So I decided to compile the sources using `./configure --with-python & make & make install` in the source folder. I then copied the folder `GDAL-x.x.x/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/osgeo` to the blender modules directory and got this time the error when importing : `ImportError: /home/yvesu/.config/blender/2.73/scripts/modules/osgeo/_gdal.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct`.
- Trying to compile with python3 using `python3 setup.py build` returns the error `error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`

**EDIT 1**: 
I think I've found the solution : I went to the directory `swig/python` (not found in a GDAL-1.11.0 folder but gdal-1.11.0 fodler, can't remember where I downloaded it from), ran `python3 setup.py build & python3 setup.py install` and could finally find the folder in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/GDAL-1.11.0-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo`. When I put this osgeo folder oni the Blender modules directory, I was able to import osgeo in Blender. I will report if anything went wrong.

I think I've listed all my attempts at installing GDAL on Ubuntu. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Do you think it is even possible to install it as a standalone module, or do I need linked libraries through LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I've found :

- Download Gdal sources (v2.0.0 is the current stable release) from ftp://ftp.remotesensing.org/gdal/2.0.0/ or http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.0.0/ and untar
- Go to the directory gdal2.0.0/swig/python
- Run python3 setup.py build & python3 setup.py install
- Finally find the module folder in, on Ubuntu : /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/GDAL-2.0.0-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo

I can now use it in Blender (copying in the modules directory)